# Creating Form in Center Screen in GWT/GXT?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am using GXT 2.3.1 ,
 I want to create a form on the center screen.

So i Used form example from the demo [Form Example](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#forms)
and `CenterLayout` as given in the demo [EXT GWT Explorer](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#centerlayout)

but it doesnt appear to be similar as given in Demo. neither its the from is in Center.

can any body explain this.??

my code

```
public class EmpDetails extends LayoutContainer {


private VerticalPanel EmpVP;
private FormData formData;

public EmpDetails() {

    formData = new FormData("-20");

    EmpVP = new VerticalPanel();  
    EmpVP.setSpacing(10); 
    createForm();
    setLayout(new CenterLayout());
    add(EmpVP);
}


private void createForm() {// some textboxes and radio button from demo example}
```

output screen
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `HorizontalAlignment`. The table that is auto-generated by GWT is not having width 100% in this case. Just set it using css.

```
public EmpDetails() {

    formData = new FormData("-20");

    empVP = new VerticalPanel(); 
    empVP.setStyleName("topPanel"); 
    empVP.setSpacing(10); 
    createForm();
    empVP.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    add(empVP);
}
```

css:

```
.topPanel > table{
    width:100%;
}
```

set the style attribute for `FormPanel` if you want all the title to be left aligned.

you can move it to a separate style in css.

```
    FormPanel simple = new FormPanel();
    ...
    simple.setStyleAttribute("text-align", "left");
```

Note: Follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

in EmpDetails constructor use these ::

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(empVP.getElement(), "marginLeft", "auto");
DOM.setStyleAttribute(empVP.getElement(), "marginRight", "auto");     

DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "marginLeft", "auto");
DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "marginRight", "auto");
```